# How to close an activity when the phone state goes to idle?

Tags: android

i want to know how to close an activity when the phone state goes to idle. i could open an activity when the phone state went "Off-Hook" from the service. Now, i need to close that activity. any help would be appreciated.

**Here is my code :**

```
public class OnCallListener extends Service {
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
TelephonyManager mgr;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mgr= (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),OnCall.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        //mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
                    } 
                      if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
                    {  


                    **//Here i want to close the activity which i opened in "Off-Hook" state**




                    }

                    }

                };

                     mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

}
```

Comment: hay i have same problem please provide me solution if you have

Answer (score 0):

start that activity with an intent that contains a flag (eg an extra) to tell your activity to close

in your acitivty you can override [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) read the flag and call `finish()` if the activity is meant to close.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a local broadcast from the service to notify the Activity to close itself. In your Activity's onResume, register for that specific broadcast and call finish(). For example:

Service code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.ACTION_COMPLETED);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter(ACTION_COMPLETED);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onPhoneIdle, f);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(onPhoneIdle);
    super.onPause();
}

private BroadcastReceiver onPhoneIdle = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to close the Activity do simply

Write a broadcast receiver in your Activity like this

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   finish();                                   
             }
     };
```

register it in your onCreate method :

```
onCreate(){

    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter("brcdt"));
}
```

don't forget to unregister it :

```
onDestroy(){

unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
}
```

send a Broadcast to revoke your Boradcast receiver from where you want to close the Activity

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("brcdt"));
```

Comment: In my code, do i need to create one more dummy activity? . and, please help me, where to put "sendBroadcast(new Intent("brcdt"));" in my code.

Comment: No put the code on your same Activify and sendBroadcast fire it from your service